# Sorting file lines in natural order

Tags: java, sorting, file

I'm new to Java and have been through some tutorials and I'm in the next step of checking how I'm doing now. Is there a better way of doing this?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Vector;

import org.apache.log4j.helpers.FileWatchdog;


/**
* 
* Simple class that reads in a file - sorts its lines in natural order,  
* writes it back out to the given filename and adds a timestamp of when it was sorted
* 
* Program will be called with:
* 
* java TestClass <input_filename> <output_filename>
*
*/

public class TestClass {


public static void main(String [] args) throws RuntimeException{
    boolean OVERWRITE_FILE = true;
    //get filename from args
    String inputFilename = args[0];
    String outputFilename = args[1];

    //check usage
    if(args.length != 2){
        System.out.println("Incorrect number of args");
        System.out.println("Correct usage is:");
        System.out.println(" java TestClass <input_filename> <output_filename> ");
        System.exit(-1);
    }

    //read in file into collection
    try {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFilename));
        Vector fileContents = new Vector<Object>();
        while(in.ready()){
            fileContents.add(in.readLine());
        }

        //sort the collection in natural order
        Collections.sort(fileContents);

        //add timestamp
        fileContents.add("File Sorted on: ");
        fileContents.add(new Date());

        //write outputFile
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputFilename, OVERWRITE_FILE));
        for(int i = 0; i < fileContents.size(); i++){
            out.write((String)fileContents.get(i) + "\n");
        }
        //close output file
        out.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error while performing IO");
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Welcome to Code Review.

Before reviewing your code, it needs to be fixed:

### First, make it work...

1. **Usage is never printed**

   Your program is supposed to print the usage instructions if the wrong number of parameters ist supplied. Check what happens if you run it without any parameters:

   > Exception in thread "main"
   >
   > ```
   > java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
   > at codereview.TestClass.main(TestClass.java:30)
   > ```

   To fix this, you need to check the length of `args` *before* accessing `args[0]` and `args[1]`.
2. **Failure because of unnecessary cast**
   If the correct number of arguments is supplied, your program will fail with the following output:

   > Exception in thread "main"
   >
   > ```
   > java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.lang.String
   > at codereview.TestClass.main(TestClass.java:59)
   > ```

   This is because you inserted a `Date` object into your `fileContents` Vector. Please **thoroughly study generics** as a better understanding of this important topic would have prevented the error.

   For now, just remove the cast `(String)fileContents.get(i)` and test your code. A complete solution is given later in this answer. *No, **really** run your code now.* You'll see that there is another problem:
3. **Sorting is not in the natural order**

   You are sorting a list of Strings. This means that the sort order will always be *alphabetical* (1,3,10,12 would be sorted as 1,10,12,3) even though your documentation comments state that the lines are sorted in their *natural* order. You can't promise to do that without knowing what kind of input they contain. As it currently stands, you should just change your comments.
4. **You are appending to the end of the output file**
   The signature of the `FileWriter` constructor is:

   ```
   public FileWriter(String fileName, boolean append) throws IOException
   ```

   So your `OVERWRITE_FILE` is a lie. Rename it to `APPEND_FILE` and set it to false (a cleaner, completely different solution will be given below).

---

### ... then, clean it up.

#### General issues

- You have several unused imports. Remove them.
- `RuntimeException` is *unchecked*, so you should remove `throws RuntimeException` from `main`.
- Your error messages are unhelpful. `Error performing IO` does not tell the user what went wrong.

### Code structure

Readability, maintainability, reusability: you should strive to achieve these three goals in your code (apart from correctness, of course, which goes above all else). One problem with your code is that *everything happens directly inside `main`*. You should *delegate* the bulk of your work into helper methods:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try
    {
        validateNumberOfArguments(args.length);
        String inputFilename = args[0];
        String outputFilename = args[1];
        List<String> lines = readLinesFrom(inputFilename);
        sortAndAddTimestampTo(lines);
        writeLinesTo(outputFilename, lines);
    }
    catch (IOException e){
        exitBecause("Error accessing file", e);
    }
}
```

This gives a nice overview of what your code does - similar to article headings in a newspaper or chapters in a book.

Here's the implementation. Your `main` has been split up into concise methods. Each of them does one thing, so they are easy to understand.

```
private static void validateNumberOfArguments(int length) {
    if (length != 2) {
        exitBecause("Incorrect number of args", "Correct usage is:", 
        "java TestClass <input_filename> <output_filename>");
    }
}

private static List<String> readLinesFrom(String path) throws IOException {
    return Files.readAllLines(getPath(path), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
}

private static void sortAndAddTimestampTo(List<String> lines) {
    Collections.sort(lines);
    lines.add("File sorted on: ");
    lines.add(new Date().toString());
}

private static void writeLinesTo(String path, List<String> lines) throws IOException {
    Files.write(getPath(path), lines, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
}

private static Path getPath(String fileName) {
    return new File(fileName).toPath();
}

private static void exitBecause(Object... reasons) {
    for (Object reason : reasons) {
        System.out.println(reason);
    }
    System.exit(-1);
}
```

Required imports (JRE7):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
```

The error messages will now be a bit more helpful:

```
Error accessing file
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: input.txt
```

or

```
Error accessing file
java.io.IOException: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by 
another process
```